# Can MVC do something Web Forms can't? (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm sort of new to asp.net. I know both MVC and Web Forms have their advantages and disadvantages, but I'm more familiar with Web Forms so I've only used that.

I was just wondering if there's something MVC can do that Web Forms can't?

From what I've understood, it's basically just different ways to code but you can get the same results from either.

This may have already been answered but I can't seem to find something that's only doable by MVC or only by Web Forms.

Thanks.

Comment: It''s all about maintainability and separation of concerns.

Comment: Mvc is based on model view controller while asp.net webforms is a mess, in context of state management,  while mvc is much better

Comment: Web forms do everything which can MVC.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad can you please clarify what you just said about "state management"?

Comment: @EdSF in web forms on every event post back happens and we have to maintain  controls state to some extent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking "Can MVC do something that Webforms can't" is like asking "can you store papers in a well organized filing cabinet that you couldn't in a pile on your desk?" The answer, really, is no.  The difference between MVC and Webforms is not functionality, it's ease of development, ease of maintainance and scalability. There are problems that webforms handles more naturally (very few IMHO, but they exist) and problems that MVC handles more naturally.

As an additional point, your question could actually be applied to any two frameworks or languages (assuming that some component of the framework is Turing Complete). Not only could you do anything in Webforms in MVC and visa versa, but you could implement the entire functionality of either in C, or R, or COBOL, or TSQL. Choosing a programming tool is about what it *can* do but what it does *easily.*

Answer (score 0):

Web forms do everything which can MVC. Its just matter of maintainability, testing, separation between layers etc.

See Java can do everything which can C# , but C# have some more features then Java which make programmer's life easy .

Mostly programmer use new Design Patterns  due to their advance features like AngularJs now replacing Jquery due to  its advance features like Declarative Way, Directive, Routes, Two way binding. Jquery can also do everything which AngularJs can. But AngularJs more robust then jquery in terms of performance, testing, maintainability, separation of concerns.